# How can I use a type enum to avoid me using strings when I specify a type in my code?

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
var types = Get("07").ToList();
```

This is for City Types

```
var types = Get("08").ToList();
```

This is for Street Types

Is there a way I can use something like an enum where I write:

```
var types = Get(TYPE.City).ToList();
var types = Get(TYPE.Street).ToList();
```

Update:

I also would be pleased to hear of any better alternatives. Thanks

Comment: would be good to see how your `Get` function works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're really after using an `enum`, do something like this:

```
public enum TYPE {
    City = 7,
    Street = 8
};

var types = Get(TYPE.City.ToString("00")).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks. I was thinking enum would be cleaner than class but it seems to be more code. Am I correct?

Comment: Should probably suggest changing the param type of the `Get` function too

Comment: @Angela: Forget about trying to write "less code", focus on writing code that is easier to maintain

Comment: @musefan It still accepts a `String` in case the leading zero is relevant.

Comment: Yeah but I figure the `Get` function would be better off using the enum too. Of course it depends on the implementation and logic. I just don't see the point in factoring out the use of strings only to use strings in the `Get` function anyway (assuming there is something like a `switch` in there - again, it depends)

Comment: @musefan Yep, if the leading zero isn't needed it's much better to just pass the `enum`.

Comment: Either way, easier to make the `ToString` call inside the `Get` if that really is what it needs to be. If the `Get` function is used by other code that always has to pass a string value then perhaps an overloaded `Get` function is the way to go... just thinking out loud really, not saying I disagree with your answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an `enum` you can create a `class`.

```
public static class TYPE
{
    public static readonly string City = "07";
    public static readonly string Street = "08";
}

// Usage:
var types = Get(TYPE.City).ToList(); // this evaluates to .Get("07")
```

Comment: ... why seal and hide the constructor rather than making the class static?

Comment: How I then call this. Would it be just like in my question? Also can you tell me what "sealed" means here? Thanks

Comment: If you're going that route why not just make the class `static`?

Comment: @Rawling and Yuck: already done. Angela: I added usage to my answer.

Comment: Would it be better if these were constants?

Comment: @Angela you can only decide this yourself. Here's an article: C# static readonly vs constant variables: when to use each: http://devlicio.us/blogs/joe_niland/archive/2006/09/27/C_2300_-static-readonly-vs-constant-variables_3A00_-when-to-use-each.aspx

Comment: @DennisTraub for this specific case constants are better. I see no justification for static readonly. In general, a good rule of thumb is to `go with constants unless there's a good reason not to.`

Comment: Can someone tell me why this static class approach is better than using Settings.Default.City and .Street and setting them there?  I like the class idea but I know that people I work with just pile stuff into the settings area.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `static` class

```
public static class TYPE
{
    public static string City = "07";
    public static string Street = "08";
}
```

Comment: How would I think do the call?

Answer (score 1):

You can create class with constants or static readonly fields that contains these values.

For example:

```
static class TYPE
{
    public const string City = "07";
    public const string Street = "08";
}
```